# Stuck in creating a rounded view with dashed lines but with multiple colors

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, layer

I want to create this kind of design in my application (image added). I have tried creating this with the replicator layer but How can i manage the different colors in this pattern?

```
    let replicatorLayer = CAReplicatorLayer()
    replicatorLayer.frame.size = viewForReplicatorLayer.frame.size
    replicatorLayer.masksToBounds = true
    replicatorLayer.instanceColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    
    let radius = viewForReplicatorLayer.frame.size.width/2 - 30
    let circum = 2 * CGFloat.pi * radius
    let num = circum/10 + 21
    let instanceCount = num//100//viewForReplicatorLayer.frame.width / image!.size.width
    replicatorLayer.instanceCount = Int(instanceCount)//Int(ceil(instanceCount))
    replicatorLayer.instanceDelay = 1.0
    viewForReplicatorLayer.layer.addSublayer(replicatorLayer)
        
    let layer = CALayer()
    let x = viewForReplicatorLayer.bounds.midX
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: 3, height: 10)
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    replicatorLayer.addSublayer(layer)
    let angle = Float.pi * 2 / Float(instanceCount)
    replicatorLayer.instanceTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(angle), 0, 0, 1)
```

This is what i want to make:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a conic gradient layer with your desired colors and then use the replicator layer to mask this gradient layer.

Create gradient layer with desired colors:

```
let orangeColor = UIColor(red: 236.0 / 255.0, green: 184.0 / 255.0, blue: 63.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let purpleColor = UIColor(red: 172.0 / 255.0, green: 56.0 / 255.0, blue: 213.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = viewForReplicatorLayer.bounds
gradientLayer.type = .conic
gradientLayer.colors = [
    orangeColor.cgColor,
    purpleColor.cgColor,
    purpleColor.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor
]
let center = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.startPoint = center
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
viewForReplicatorLayer.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Set replicator layer as mask of the gradient layer:

```
gradientLayer.mask = replicatorLayer
```

Since we're using replicator layer as mask, no need to add it as a sublayer anymore so remove the following from your existing code:

```
viewForReplicatorLayer.layer.addSublayer(replicatorLayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You start from orange, which is in RGB (1; 0.5; 0) and you go up to purple which is in RGB (1; 0; 1).

```
R: 1   -> 1
G: 0.5 -> 0
B: 0   -> 1
```

So, we just need to replicate that:

```
replicatorLayer.instanceBlueOffset = 1 / Float(instanceCount)
replicatorLayer.instanceGreenOffset = -(1.0 / Float(instanceCount * 2)) //There is the 2 factor because because this color speed is twice less the blue one
```

Some other changes:

```
replicatorLayer.instanceColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.5, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
...
layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Comment: How do you calculate the instanceBlueOffset and greenoffset?

Comment: See the "B: from 0 to 1" and G to "0.5 to 0". Then devide the value by number of steps?